# How can I enable a button inside a disabled ListboxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listboxitem

I have a ListBox in Wpf, filled with ListBoxItems - each item contains a file object and an "info button". These file objects contains file properties - such as filename, path, etc -, but some of these files are invalid, which is marked by a flag.

I want to disable the listbox items which contains an invalid file except info button inside.

I successfully disabled the whole Listbox Item on invalid elements, but it's not correct because every file object (no matter that invalid or not) contains a specific file information. This could be shown on clicking the info button.

This code works well, but the result is that every elemenet inside the Listbox Item are disabled. I want that button element to be enabled.

[image: The result as image]

And the code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="fileNameListBox" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding FileListViewModel.FilteredFileList, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" 
                     Margin="0, 0, 0, 5"
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Left">

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FileListSelectionChangedCommand}"
                                           CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=fileNameListBox, Path=SelectedItem}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>

            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="{Binding Filename}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <Label Content="{Binding FilePath}" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="10"/>
                        <Button x:Name="infoButton" Width="50" Content="Info" FontWeight="Light" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:FileListView}}, Path=DataContext.FileListViewModel.FileInfoClickedCommand }"
                                CommandParameter="{Binding}" /> <!-- I want this button to be enabled -->
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsValid}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
```

So, my question is that is there a way to enable every button in these ListBox Items? Or can I make this with another tricky solution?

Comment: Windows controls are hierarchical; disabling anything that contains other controls effectively disables them too. You might need to alter your hierarchy and make the button a peer or a parent of the thing that shows the info, not a child of it

Comment: Add the `DataTrigger` to the `DataTemplate` and remove the `ItemContainerStyle` triggers. Inside the `DataTemplate` disable the required controls by using the `Setter.TargetName` property. But since the `Button` is the only user input control inside the item, this trigger is not needed. Removing the trigger alone will achieve what you want.

Comment: Instead of disabling the entire `ListBoxItem`, you could disable all controls but the `Button`. If you want to disable the mouse over highlighting of the containers, you could define a custom `ControlTemplate`.